# Bash as default shell for Netware user

Tags: unix, unix-shell, novell

I am connecting to the Novell Netware (OES) server via ssh. It shows me default novell console. I want it to start bash automatically when I connect. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike SSH for Linux, SSH for NetWare doesn't come with the kind of /etc/passwd or PAM-Ldap hooks needed to specify a default shell. It also doesn't assume it's running a shell or running login scripts, which makes it further unlike Linux-SSH. It is assumed that when you SSH into a NetWare server you're an admin looking to do remote administration, and therefore you need Console. It is meant as a kind of rconsole replacement.

Because of this, you have to explicitly enter bash when you SSH into a NetWare server, it won't do it for you.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Note that dmityugov's reference is to the Unix profile, which is only active when a user logs into an actual Unix-like OS such as Linux or Solaris and has no effect in Netware.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! I understood. This is very strange console. It's only rewriting the same window every time with esc-sequences. So, it's seems hard to automate this process. I mean connect to the server, execute some commands, and then analyze the output. Maybe there is another way to make such automatic checks, more efficient than common ssh connection?

Comment: Now that I think about it, you could specify that bash start at server boot (by putting "bash" into the autoexec.ncf file) and that would leave it there for you whenever you remoted in.

Answer (score 0):

The user you're connecting as either has the console set as their shell (`chsh`), or has the console set to run in their shell startup scripts.

Comment: chsh is not working in Novell bash. Where shell startup scripts in Netware could be? I can't find out how to change user's default shell in Netware like I did it other unix (in /etc/passwd)

Comment: Weird. Then the startup scripts should be hidden in the user's home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but in ConsoleOne, in UNIX Profile tab for a user, you can specify the shell. In particular, you can set it to Bash. It seems it also possible to do this via  [iManager](http://www.novell.com/support/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=7000180&sliceId=1&docTypeID=DT_TID_1_1)